# Reducing size of rebar-generated upgrade packages

Tags: erlang, upgrade, rebar

I'm currently learning how to make erlang releases and release upgrades using rebar. Thanks to [this tutorial](http://www.metabrew.com/article/erlang-rebar-tutorial-generating-releases-upgrades) I was already able to successfully generate releases and upgrades, but one issue has emerged during this.

In a project that I'm working on, it is important that release upgrades are as small as possible, because they are downloaded through unreliable and slow connection into an embedded device (e.g. beagleboard)

Unfortunately, tar.gz archives generated by rebar always contain a full release, with all applications. I was wondering if there is a method to make a working release upgrade that would contain only new applications and updated applications to reduce archive size. Maybe it is possible to configure reltool to do that?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a small guide on the issue as [part of Learn You Some Erlang's releases chapter](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/release-is-the-word#recipes):

Here's one of the release files presented to make things smaller:

```
{sys, [
 {lib_dirs, ["/home/ferd/code/learn-you-some-erlang/release/"]},
 {erts, [{mod_cond, derived},
         {app_file, strip}]},
 {rel, "erlcount", "1.0.0", [kernel, stdlib, ppool, erlcount]},
 {boot_rel, "erlcount"},
 {relocatable, true},
 {profile, embedded}, 
 {app_file, strip},
 {debug_info, strip},
 {incl_cond, exclude},
 {excl_app_filters, ["_tests.beam$"]},
 {app, stdlib, [{mod_cond, derived}, {incl_cond, include}]},
 {app, kernel, [{incl_cond, include}]},
 {app, ppool, [{vsn, "1.0.0"}, {incl_cond, include}]},
 {app, erlcount, [{vsn, "1.0.0"}, {incl_cond, include}]}
]}.
```

This strips debug info, makes app files as small as possible, removes test files, excludes as many applications as possible, etc. Note that you will need to at least include SASL and keep the debug_info if you want people to be able to run live code upgrades of your material.

All in all, the ERTS itself takes 18.5MB. That's going to be most of your space if you use the rules above, so you have to check whether or not you can drop some executables (non-SMP Erlang, etc.) from the list.